# C++ validate user input is a single character

Tags: c++

optionTest is a string, and option is a char. The issue occurs when I enter something like "ee e". The last "e" is grabbed despite my ignore/clear. I want the validation loop to run as long as the input is not a single character.

```
    cin >> optionTest;

    while (optionTest.length() != 1) {
        cout << "Invalid input. please try again." << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        cin.clear();
        //receive option
        cin >> optionTest;
    }

    option = optionTest[0];
```

Comment: Why not simply grabbing input for a single `char` rather than a `std::string` in first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`std::basic_istream::ignore()`'s description](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore):

> `basic_istream& ignore( std::streamsize count = 1, int_type delim = Traits::eof() );`
>
> it extracts characters from the stream and discards them until any one of the following conditions occurs:
>
> `count` characters were extracted. This test is disabled in the special case when `count` equals `std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max()`

Since you call it with empty parentheses, `count` is 1 and thus only one character is extracted (space character, in  your case).

Try `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max())` (or at least any number sufficiently large).

Comment: Thank you. Setting the ignore count to my optionTest.length() did the trick. I would upvote, but my account is brand new.

Comment: Perhaps it accidentally did? Your `optionTest` is but two characters ("ee"), and thus by ignoring two chars you've managed to skip the remaining " e" but will you be so lucky next line?